# Ajax post filter with radio buttons in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to make an Ajax post filter with radio buttons. So that the user can filter through multiple categories using the radio buttons.

This is the code I used:

Front-end form:

```
<form id="filter">
            <?php
                if( $terms = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name' ) ) : // to make it simple I use default categories
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="' . $term->term_id . '" class="br">' . $term->name;
                    echo '';
                endforeach;
                endif;
            ?>
            <div class="filter-output"></div>
        </form>
```

Script.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#filter .br').click(function(){

        // Declaratie van array
        var choices = {};

        $('.contents').remove();
        $('.filter-output').empty();

        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
            if (!choices.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) 
                choices[this.name] = [this.value];
            else 
                choices[this.name].push(this.value);
        });


        console.log(choices);
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
            type :'POST',
            data : {
                'action' : 'call_post', // Naam van de PHP functie
                'choices' : choices,
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $('.filter-output').append(result);
                // Voor testen - Resultaat (Kan later verwijderd worden)
                //console.log(Resultaat);
                //console.log(Keuzes);
            },
            error: function(err){
                // Voor testen - Error (Kan later verwijderd worden)
                console.log(err);
                console.log(choices);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_call_post', 'call_post');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_call_post', 'call_post');

function call_post(){

// Verkijgen van AJAX data:
$choices = $_POST['choices'];

$meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');
foreach($choices as $Key=>$Value){

    if(count($Value)){
        foreach ($Value as $Inkey => $Invalue) {
            $meta_query[] = array( 'key' => $Key, 'value' => $Invalue, 'compare' => '=' );
        }
    }
}
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' =>$meta_query
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
 //if( ! empty ($params['template'])) {
     ////$template = $params['template'];
     if( $query->have_posts() ) :
         while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
             get_template_part('content');
         endwhile;
         wp_reset_query();
     else :
         wp_send_json($query->posts);
     endif;
 //}

die(); }
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> script.js:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxobject is not defined

And I'm not sure how to solve it. So I hope someone can help me. I have very little experience with AJAX thats why I'm asking for help.

Link to the website: 
http://5.79.72.162/~delta/category/vacancies/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly identifies the issue here.
'ajaxobject' does not seem to be defined in the shared snippet.
The error is not related to AJAX but more of Javascript variable not assigned before usage.

You need to define ajaxobject via Javascript code and then set 'ajaxurl' in it.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#filter .br').click(function(){

        // Declaratie van array
        var choices = {};

        $('.contents').remove();
        $('.filter-output').empty();

        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
            if (!choices.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) 
                choices[this.name] = [this.value];
            else 
                choices[this.name].push(this.value);
        });

        // Define ajaxobject
        var ajaxobject = {
            ajaxurl: "your_web_service_url"
        };
        console.log(choices);
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxobject.ajaxurl,
            type :'POST',
            data : {
                'action' : 'call_post', // Naam van de PHP functie
                'choices' : choices,
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $('.filter-output').append(result);
                // Voor testen - Resultaat (Kan later verwijderd worden)
                //console.log(Resultaat);
                //console.log(Keuzes);
            },
            error: function(err){
                // Voor testen - Error (Kan later verwijderd worden)
                console.log(err);
                console.log(choices);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you :), It required the connection to the admin-ajax.php. Now just going to have to find out why it is not displaying the information whilst making the arrays.